# Apache RewriteRule not rewriting as expected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can you any one see anything wrong with the following apache rewrite rule:

This is in my .htaccess file inside a folder called "text" a subdirectory of `localhost/lombardpress` I have the following rule

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([^/]+) /textdisplay.php?fs=$1 [NC]
```

I was expecting this input:

```
http://localhost/lombardpress-dev/text/lectio1
```

to rewrite to this:

```
http://localhost/lombardpress-dev/text/textdisplay?fs=lectio1
```

But instead I get a 404 error.

> The requested URL /textdisplay.php was not found on this server.

It looks to me like the RewriteRule has re-written the address but not as I intended - so there must be something wrong with my regular expression.

Let me know if I can provide further information.

Comment: You should use RewriteBase /lombardpress-dev/text/ and remove the first slash from this /textdisplay.php?fs=$1 to this textdisplay.php?fs=$1

Comment: I'm not familiar with RewriteBase. Could you write out what that would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /lombardpress-dev/text/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/]+) textdisplay.php?fs=$1 [NC]
```

With that rewrite cond you wont redirect textdisplay.php to itself again.
The problem is that [^/]+ matches all but / so it matches even textdisplay.php

Comment: So this gets me very close, however, ([^/]+) is returning "textdisplay.php" only if write (le.*) does it return "lectio1" and work -- very strange. I don't understand why it should match "textdisplay.php" since 'textdisplay.php' is not at all present in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove leading slash in target URL:

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ textdisplay.php?fs=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `/` in front of the target:

```
RewriteRule ([^/.]+) textdisplay.php?fs=$1 [NC]
# no slash here ----^
```